# CSP added but Lighthouse flags it as missing

Tags: seo-audit, content-security-policy, lighthouse

Ive added a CSP via PHP but Lighthouse is still saying

'Ensure CSP is effective against XSS attacks'

Heres my CSP, is there something missing or set incorrectly that could be causing Lighthouse to flag it?

```
header("Content-Security-Policy: default-src 'self'  *.fonts.googleapis.com; style-src fonts.googleapis.com; style-src-elem 'self' fonts.googleapis.com; font-src 'self' fonts.gstatic.com; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'  'nonce-$nonce'; object-src 'none'; base-uri 'self'; report-uri http://mydomain.co.uk ");
```

I created the CSP one instruction at a time and throughout the process Lighthouse kept telling me which instructions were missing or failing but once Id completed all of them it no longer told me anything was missing or incorrect but still flagged it as an issue?

Comment: Google's own [CSP evaluator](https://csp-evaluator.withgoogle.com/) shows no syntax issues with your CSP, but it does show some warnings. Maybe Lighthouse was getting caught up on warnings similar to the ones showing there?

Comment: Thanks, thats a useful tool which I was unaware of. I fixed the issue it brought up but still get the warnings in dev console

Answer (score 1):

Based on the Content Security Policy (CSP) you've provided, it appears to be mostly correctly structured. However, there is one issue in your CSP directive:

You have a typo in the style-src directive. You've listed it twice, and the second one is missing -elem. It should be combined as follows:

```
style-src 'self' fonts.googleapis.com;
```

With this correction, your CSP header should look like this:

```
header("Content-Security-Policy: default-src 'self' *.fonts.googleapis.com; style-src 'self' fonts.googleapis.com; font-src 'self' fonts.gstatic.com; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'nonce-$nonce'; object-src 'none'; base-uri 'self'; report-uri http://mydomain.co.uk");
```

After making this change, Lighthouse should no longer flag it as an issue related to the effectiveness of your CSP against XSS attacks, assuming there are no other issues with your website's code that might be causing this warning.